# ruby, rubygems & rails - getting everything in the right place!

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So - a little bit of background on the system I'm running.
I'm on a Mac running Snow Leopard.

I know that Snow Leopard comes pre-installed with Ruby and Rails - but I think I may have messed things up as I found this out after I installed Ruby and Rails again.

When I run ruby -v it displays that I am running ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]. Even though I've gone through the process to try and install 1.9.2!

When I run rails -v it displays that I am running Rails 2.3.5

When I run mysql -v it displays that I am running 5.1.56 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

I can get into the interactive ruby shell and I can get into mysql prompt.
However, when I try to run ruby script/console, it comes up with:
ruby: No such file or directory -- script/console (LoadError)

Furthermore, when I attempt to setup a new folder for a rails project it comes up with the following:

```
rails railsproject
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:55: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)
  from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require'
  from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'
  from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support.rb:56
  from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require'
  from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'
  from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/bin/../lib/rails_generator.rb:28
  from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require'
  from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'
  from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/bin/rails:14
  from /usr/bin/rails:19:in `load'
  from /usr/bin/rails:19
```

Which directory should I have installed the ruby and rubygems folders into?
Also, do I need to be in a specific directory for the ruby script/console command to work properly?

This is very frustrating - as I tried to uninstall and reinstall ruby and rubgygems multiple times...

Complete newbie with this - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers
Rick

Answer (score 4):

My advice would be to remove all existing packages and use the [Ruby Version Manager](https://rvm.io) instead. Just visit the page follow the installation instructions and everything will be fine.

Comment: i tried to install GIT (as this is required for installing RVM) - but when I try and run the DMG it states that the file couldn't be recognised. I downloaded the most recent version of it as well... any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I am on Ubuntu, don't know how to install git on Mac, but it is definately possible, as many Rails developers are using git on their macs.

Answer (score 0):

[Pragmatic Studio](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac) has some instructions for ruby 1.9 and rails 3. These are the directions they give students before participating in one of their courses. Pragmatic Studio also publishes a lot of great ruby/rails books so you could say they're a trusted resource.